# Как сделать отрисовку метки каждые 5 сек?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui

Допустим хочу сделать, чтобы метка менялась на другую каждые 5 секунд.

Пока есть вот такой вариант:

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()
root.title('main')
root.geometry('400x400')

def develop_label():
    
    l1 = Label(text = '1', font = 'TimesNewRoman 12')
    l1.place(x=10,y=10)

    #time.sleep(5) #in sec

    l2 = Label(text = '2', font = 'TimesNewRoman 12')
    l2.place(x=10,y=50)

    l3 = Label(text = '3', font = 'TimesNewRoman 12')
    l3.place(x=10,y=90)
    
develop_label()
root.mainloop()
```

`time.sleep` пока закомментировал, ибо всё равно не работает, как задумывал.

Каким методом можно воспользоваться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('main')
root.geometry('400x400')


def develop_label(mark_index):
    marks = ['1', '2', '3']
    l1['text'] = marks[mark_index]  # меняем свойство text виджета на значение из списка marks
    if mark_index == len(marks) - 1:  # если сейчас последний элемент
        mark_index = -1
    root.after(5000, develop_label, mark_index + 1)  # (интервал в мс, функция, аргумент функции)


l1 = Label(text='1', font='TimesNewRoman 12')
l1.place(x=10, y=10)

root.after(0, develop_label, 0)  # (интервал в мс, функция, аргумент функции)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте так:

```
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime

root = Tk()
root.title('main')
root.geometry('400x400')

temp = 0
after_id = ""

def tick(temp):
    after_id = root.after(1000, lambda: tick(temp))
    f_temp = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(temp).strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    l1.configure(text=str(f_temp))
    temp += 1

l1 = Label(text = '1', font = 'TimesNewRoman 12')
l1.place(x=10, y=10)

l2 = Label(text = '2', font = 'TimesNewRoman 12')
l2.place(x=10, y=50)

l3 = Label(text = '3', font = 'TimesNewRoman 12')
l3.place(x=10, y=90)

tick(temp)
root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]